# How to mount command or busybox to docker container?

Tags: docker

The image pulled from docker hub is a minimal system, without commands like vim,ping,etc. Sometimes when in debug environment.

For example, I need `ping` to test network or "vim" to modify conf, but I don`t want to install them in container or in`docker-file` as they are not necessary in run time.

I have tried to install the commands in my container which is not convenient.
So, I think if it can mount commands from host to container? or even "mount" a busy-box to container?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [ask] and take the [tour] to get a quick overview how you might get high quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

You **should** install these tools in your docker container, because this is how the things are done. I cant find a single reason not to do so, but in case you cant do it (**why??**), you can put necessary binaries into volume and mount this volume into your container. Something like:

```
docker run -it -v /my/binaries/here:/binaries:ro image sh

$ ls /binaries
```

and execute them inside using container path `/binaries`.

But what you have to keep in mind - these binaries usually **have dependencies** from system paths like `/var/lib` and others. And when calling them from inside container, you have to somehow resolve them.

Comment: Thanks! my question is a little unreasonable, this question come to me suddenly when I install tools in my container, I thought if the tools can be packaged into a 'box' which can be easily mounted or unmounted instead of installing,that would be wonderful.

Comment: @mingxie Your question is totally reasonable and a good practice. I'm building containers images for Go programs and I want no other binaries than my program. Smaller image transfer. Smaller attack surface.

Answer (score 0):

If running on Kubernetes, the `kubectl` command has support for running a debug container that has access to running container. Check `kubectl debug`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container